# CodeIgniter output XML in View

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I tried to output XML in the view file. The view file is `result_view.php` and its first line is

`<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>`

But I get the error "Content is not allowed in prolog". So how to do this correctly? I use Eclipse + PDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this causes any problem, but I disabled PHP short open tag in .htaccess file, and `<?xml` worked. PHP no longer attempted to parse `<?` as php script.

Answer (score 10):

One easy solution is to set php header in the view file and then echo the xml header.

**Put this in the top of your view file:**

```
<?php header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error seems to indicate that you have data before your <?xml ?> declaration. You might have a **[Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)** at the beginning of your file.

Try opening your file in an editor that will allow you to remove any BOM (such as Notepad++), or an editor with the capability to view files in hexadecimal format. There are also several tools you can use for removing BOMs. Google for more info, as the tool you use will vary depending on your situation and environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
<&#063;xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"&#063;>
```

In html looks good, BUT then the receiver (application) must replace the `and#063;` to `?`.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter 4 update

```
    $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using php tags to echo out a simple string?

How about just putting this at the top of your view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: @Daniel Yes short tags seem to be the problem